# Export Layer to KML. Hyperlink in attribute field is inactive

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, google-earth, hyperlink, layer-to-kml

I'm working on exporting layers from ArcMap 10.6 to KMLs for use in Google Earth Pro. There is a field in the ArcMap feature class that has a file path link to our network drive to an image. The links do not stay connected when converted to KML.

First image is what I see in ArcMap. A functioning file path.
[image: This is the file path link in ArcMap.]

This is the same file path in Google Earth Pro. The link is not active.
[image: This is the inactive file path link in Google Earth Pro]

This is what I see in Google Earth Pro when I "Inspect" the file path.
[image: This is what I see when I right-click the file path in Google Earth Pro and hit "Inspect".]

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying that it's just text in the KML balloon, instead of being a clickable hyperlink?  If so, that's because your balloon HTML has only text content, and does not have the text wrapped in a link tag:

`<a href="{link URL}">{link text}</a>`

To work as a link, it would have to look something like this:

```html
<td>Photopath</td>    
<td>
  <a href="G:\Scanned Images\StructurePhotos\051 KennedyOwens\DSC01425.jpg">
    G:\Scanned Images\StructurePhotos\051 KennedyOwens\DSC01425.jpg
  </a>
</td>
```

Comment: How would I add the <a href=   Text     </a>? I've tried in Excel and Field Calculator for ArcMap but I'm having major issues. The few links I've googled all have different formulas.

Comment: In ArcMap, the field is a string type. I have thousands of scanned images on multiple feature classes. The file paths are copy/pasted from our network G: Drive. Apparently the path always worked for Google Earth until Google Earth Pro was released.

Comment: I wonder if something in GE Pro changed? I just created a field with `<a href="C:\TEMP\thumbnail.png">Open Photo</a>` and when loading it up, it didn't show a clickable link.

Comment: @Irrigation_GIS, I'm not sure how to do it in ArcGIS, hopefully others can answer that.  In my limited experience, ArcGIS has very limited support for customizing KML output, and the defaults are often not great.

Comment: @KHibma, we would need to see your full balloon HTML to debug.  Unlikely to be due to a change in Earth pro.

Comment: I see what's going on now. (I'm using Pro, maybe ArcMap is different), but everything gets placed inside a `<![CDATA[` block, and it gets escaped `<td>&lt;a href="C:\TEMP\thumbnail.png"&gt;Open Photo&lt;/a&gt;</td>` (I assume the escaped chars makes it 'not a link'). This has/can work. I've seen clickable links from ArcGIS Layer to KML tool. I just don't recall. It might be the specific styling of the HTML Popup as referenced here: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/kml/creating-kml-in-arcgis-for-desktop.htm

Comment: Yes, if something gets wrapped in "<![CDATA[...]]>", then it will be used as a text blob in the HTML, and the HTML tags will not be interpreted.  Hopefully you can find a way to update the HTML template in ArcGIS to output the correct tags.